AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'guild'
class Buttons( discord.ui.View): 
    def __init__(self, *, timeout=180): 
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
    @discord.ui.button(label="Button",style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def gray_button(self, button:discord.ui.button(), interaction:discord.Interaction):
        print(type(interaction))
        if config.guild['eventRole'] in interaction.guild.roles:
            await interaction.user.remove_roles(config.guild['eventRole'])
        else:
            await interaction.user.add_roles(config.guild['eventRole'])
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "This message has buttons!",
        view=Buttons()

Ошибка
if config.guild['eventRole'] in interaction.guild.roles:
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'guild'

Почему объект disord.Interaction неожиданно превращается discord.ui.button.Buttonи как это решить?

Могу предложить такие классы для того, чтобы создавать ui.View:
class CustomButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self, func: any, args: list | None=None, label: str | None=None, style: discord.ButtonStyle | None= discord.ButtonStyle.secondary, emoji: str | None=None, row: int | None=None) -> None:
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        super().__init__(label=label, style=style, emoji=emoji, row=row)
    
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
        if self.args == None:
            await self.func(self, interaction)
        else:
            await self.func(self, interaction, self.args)

class CustomView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, items: list, timeout: float) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        for i in items:
            self.add_item(item=i)

Вот пример использования:
async def hello_func(btn: CustomButton, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("hello", ephemeral=True)

async def world_func(btn: CustomButton, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("world", ephemeral=True)

await interaction.response.send_message(
    content = f"Какие то кнопки.",
    view = CustomView(
        items = [
            CustomButton(label="Hello", row=0, func=hello_func, style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray),
            CustomButton(label="World", row=0, func=world_func, style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
        ],
        timeout = None)
    )


Спасибо, сработало - однако вместо Interaction.responCe пришлось поставить Interaction.responSe

Обращайтесь, да, возможны ошибки, т.к. писал на свой глаз (без подсказок и исправлений ошибок). Спасибо, что заметили ошибку.

У вас очень классно получилось, правда пришлось ещё немножко подшаманить изменив третью interaction.responce... на ctx.send для вызываемых команд, но в остальном: очень читаемо и потому полезно, удобно использовать, не хрупкая структура( та которая ломается при большинстве изменений) - бомба вообщем

Функция callback (ваша gray_button) принимает только 1 аргумент interaction.
Получается так, что у вас self - это и есть объект кнопки, а button - это discord.Interaction
У вас должно получится так:
async def gray_button(self:discord.ui.Button, interaction:discord.Interaction): ...

если будут проблемы с self, то оставьте self без ":discord.ui.Button":
async def gray_button(self, interaction:discord.Interaction): ...


Traceback (most recent call):
  File "Lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 430, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "Lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 141, in __call__
    return self.callback(self.view, interaction, self.item)
TypeError: Buttons.gray_button() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given``` **одна и та же ошибка в обоих случаях**

в таком случае предлагаю вам немного другой подход к созданию кнопки, сейчас напишу и распишу

Функция принимает только два аргумента, это self и interaction.
async def callback(self, interaction:discord.Interaction):

И само название gray_button измените на callback.

абсолютно та же ошибка что и с кодом предыдущего комментатора TypeError: Buttons.callback() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
